# FromQuery with FromBody fallback

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a method which accept POST and GET verbs, How can I get a property bind from the querystring if it's a GET request and from body if it's a Post Request?

Extra point if it can databind from JSON and from form encoded bodies.

Comment: the use case that you described doesn't look like fallback related, as you need  `FromQuery` only for GET method (and vise verse for POST) . Just use different action methods for each of  HTTP methods.

Comment: You shouldn't mix it. The verbs typically imply if an action has side effects or not and if these are idempotent or not. You use GET where there are no side effects (no data is changed), POST for adding new data and PUT for replacing (idempotent - multiple calls to it will have the same result